# Как установить фон кнопка отличный от родительского фона

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, qt-designer, qss

[image: Кнопка]

Почему кнопка наследует цвет заднего фона?

Как сделать так, чтобы кнопка имела такой фон, который укажу я?

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(400, 531)
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("background-color: #22222e")
        MainWindow.setAnimated(True)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setStyleSheet("background-image: url(:/Fone/5myPN2ppKpA.jpg);")
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.weapon = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.weapon.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(140, 480, 111, 31))
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.weapon.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.weapon.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Copperplate Gothic Bold")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.weapon.setFont(font)
        self.weapon.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"color: white;\n"
"border: 2px solid #747a06;\n"
"}")
        self.weapon.setInputMethodHints(QtCore.Qt.ImhNone)
        self.weapon.setAutoExclusive(False)
        self.weapon.setObjectName("weapon")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 400, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.weapon.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Weapons"))
import ApexFone_rc


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: central widget]

---

**Update**

Вот указал, `.QWidget` (на центральный виджет), но в самой программе не отобразился задний фон, он отображается если только запустить демонстрацию программы.

ui файл

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>400</width>
    <height>531</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <property name="styleSheet">
   <string notr="true">background-color: #22222e</string>
  </property>
  <property name="animated">
   <bool>true</bool>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <property name="styleSheet">
    <string notr="true">background-image: url(:/Fone/5myPN2ppKpA.jpg);</string>
   </property>
   <widget class="QPushButton" name="weapon">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>140</x>
      <y>480</y>
      <width>111</width>
      <height>31</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="sizePolicy">
     <sizepolicy hsizetype="Preferred" vsizetype="Fixed">
      <horstretch>0</horstretch>
      <verstretch>0</verstretch>
     </sizepolicy>
    </property>
    <property name="font">
     <font>
      <family>Copperplate Gothic Bold</family>
      <pointsize>12</pointsize>
      <weight>50</weight>
      <bold>false</bold>
     </font>
    </property>
    <property name="styleSheet">
     <string notr="true">QPushButton {
color: white;
border: 2px solid #747a06;
}</string>
    </property>
    <property name="inputMethodHints">
     <set>Qt::ImhNone</set>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>Weapons</string>
    </property>
    <property name="autoExclusive">
     <bool>false</bool>
    </property>
   </widget>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>400</width>
     <height>21</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
 </widget>
 <resources>
  <include location="../our/ApexFone.qrc"/>
 </resources>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve]

Comment: @S.Nick Я оставил код, поставьте только своё изображение.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Укажите что `background-image` относится только к классу `QWidget`:

```
self.centralwidget.setStyleSheet(".QWidget {background-image: url(lena.jpg);}")
```

обратите внимание на **`.`** перед `QWidget`

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(400, 531)
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("background-color: #22222e")
        MainWindow.setAnimated(True)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        
#        self.centralwidget.setStyleSheet("background-image: url(:/Fone/5myPN2ppKpA.jpg);")
        self.centralwidget.setStyleSheet(".QWidget {background-image: url(lena.jpg);}")
#                                         ^^^^^^^^ 

        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.weapon = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.weapon.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(140, 480, 111, 31))
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.weapon.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.weapon.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Copperplate Gothic Bold")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.weapon.setFont(font)
        self.weapon.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"color: white;\n"
"background-color: blue;\n"                                    # /* <---- */
"border: 2px solid #747a06;\n"
"}")
        self.weapon.setInputMethodHints(QtCore.Qt.ImhNone)
        self.weapon.setAutoExclusive(False)
        self.weapon.setObjectName("weapon")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 400, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.weapon.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Weapons"))
#import ApexFone_rc


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

---

**Update**

> Я добавил новый скрин шот, посмотрите, задний фон не отображается, пока не запустить программу

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А можно это как-то сделать на прямую в qt designer?

Comment: @НикитаПфейфер да. так там и пишите `.QWidget {background-image: url(...);}`

Comment: Я добавил новый скрин шот, посмотрите, задний фон не отображается, пока не запустить программу

Comment: @НикитаПфейфер я не знаю куда мне смотреть. Опубликуйте свой файл `.ui`

Comment: я кинул выше код из ui файла

Comment: @НикитаПфейфер я добавил обновление, в котором показал как это надо сделать. Проверьте.

Comment: А вы пишите этот код в MainWindow или centralWidet?

Comment: Я вроде разобрался, но я хочу задать ещё один вопрос, я создам новый